# How can I create avd for the Samsung Galaxy S4 (1080X1920)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

How can I create AVD for Samsung Galaxy S4 and in which layout will it comes large or normal?

While am I creating AVD, it creating emulator in large-xxhdpi.

Comment: Instructions for Samsung Emulators for Android Studio and Eclipse are located here:

Using Samsung Emulator Skins for Android Application Development
http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000095

The skins can be downloaded here:    
http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/list.do?pi=1&ps=50&pb=Y&ct=CT350000&sc=

Answer (score 38):

Follow the steps given at below URL to create avd for Galaxy S4 smartphone. S4 and and xperia z have same screen size (5 inch) and same resolution 1080x1920.

http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/

Please note that you must also install 'Sony DeviceProfiles' under Extras within the SDK Manager, as well as 'Sony Add-On SDK'.

To exactly match the emulator, clone xperia z from "device definition" tab and chose hardware button to create user defined device and create avd from this new device.

Don't forget to check "Use host GPU emulation" option for avd also keep in mind that your system must have graphics card (GPU) installed in it.

Comment: I have followed this link and installed sony add on sdk as per the instruction. Now when I open the Xperia Z AVD , it is showing black screen. What might be the problem????

Comment: Don't forget to check "Use host GPU emulation" option for avd also keep in mind that your system must have graphics card (GPU) installed in it.

Comment: It seems to have been moved here: http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/

Comment: The link states you must install the Sony Add-on SDK, but actually you need to install 'Sony DeviceProfiles' under Extras.

Comment: The Add-on SDK page seems to have moved again: https://developer.sony.com/develop/smartphones-and-tablets/mobile-devices/get-started/ If you configure that, then Sony DeviceProfiles appears in the SDK Manager list