# Avd for Samsung Galaxy S4 not working

Tags: java, android, api, android-virtual-device

I've created an avd compatible to Samsung Galaxy S4.
here is the details for that:

1080 X 1920
API 14, Android 4.2

But when i try to run this emulator. It display nothing but a blank screen, seems not working at all.

Am i missing something ?

Can any body share his experience of working with Galaxy S4.

Comment: did you tested on s4 avd? i too have this problem.

Comment: Well i tried many time but no luck for Emulator but its working fine on real device. The most relavant reason could be that low configuration systems.

Comment: i updated sdk with sony device profiles and created an avd for xperia z which has same configuration as Samsung galaxy S4. I believe that it'l look similar in both devices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create avd for the Samsung Galaxy S4 (1080X1920)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561998/how-can-i-create-avd-for-the-samsung-galaxy-s4-1080x1920)

Comment: solve your problem ?please put the solution .

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in the "**use Host GPU**" - it should be **checked**.
I had the same problem - blank screen and AVD won't run. I edited the **AVD settings** and checked the "**use Host GPU**" - it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can install sony device profiles from sdk manager and create a new avd using the device defenition of sony xperia z because Samsung galaxy S4 and Sony Xperia Z has the same configuration, so your app will look similar in both devices.

[image: install sony device profile from sdk manager]

Answer (score 0):

You can use another option for run your app in samsung galaxy s4 .
Use samsung test device .

link:http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action