# Android App not starting - Only on Galaxy S4

Tags: android, galaxy

I'm developing a game on Android that has been running well over months on all devices I know of. But recently I noticed that S4 users typically uninstall the app right away, and finally someone with an S4 (**jflte**) wrote a review, stating that the app "**does not start**".

I cannot reproduce this behaviour in an AVD ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561998/how-can-i-create-avd-for-the-samsung-galaxy-s4-1080x1920?lq=1)) and won't have an S4 at hand any time soon. Googling the issue, I found that this is not umcommon with S4's and *might* be related to SD-card installs. I did not find any solution though. My app uses OpenGL with **android.opengl.GLSurfaceView**.

**Question is**: What are my options to investigate the problem? I've seen [the RTL option](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action#), but it seems to be some kind of premium thing. Disabling S4 support in the Play Store does not count as solution. I would love to have LogCat output of the startup attempts on an S4.

Here's my AndroidManifest, as far as relevant:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="app.orbs"
android:versionCode="24"
android:versionName="2.1"
android:installLocation="auto" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/orb_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="orbs.OrbsApplication">

    <activity
        android:name="orbs.controller.MainMenuActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="orbs.controller.GameActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>    

    <activity
        android:name="orbs.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is to try and get users to send error reports when a crash happens, but lets face it, most people won't do that.

So I would suggest looking into an automatic crash reporting system such as [Crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think that the app actually crashes in the way that an error report is generated. It just does not start.

Comment: If your app can't start, there's no way there can't be a crash.

Comment: It turns out I was hunting a ghost here. The app did indeed start and also crash on the S4 (and some other devices as well). It was not the entire app that failed to start, but only a new game within the app. I misunderstood my users comments. Thanks for the hint towards Crittercism!